# Can't do accurate weight painting with Blender

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I learned with Maya, mastered it, I am a pro. With Blender I am less than zero, a complete incompetent. The most challenging for weight painting is the butt. Default weights make the butt look like a fold when sitting so it needs fixing so that the volume of the butt doesn't shrink when the legs are bent and you don't want the torso to indent either. My solution, I have to export just to weight paint so I can use a smoothing brush and also, so I can contour an inner thigh without the brush hitting anything else.

It takes finesse and the correct tools and accurate tools as well. Selecting only affected mesh points and using the smooth function and I still can't get results. I feel like I'm using a keyboard as piano keys sure you can make music but it feels clunky and lacking.

But I must be doing something wrong as I seem to be the only one who feel like a complete incompetent that I'm willing to pay just for better weight painting tools. Maybe a plugin I could buy? Hiring someone to make a script? Anything?

At least is there a tutorial that would show me how to master weight painting in Blender? I never found any tutorials that addressed the skill of weight painting with Blender. Sure there are tutorials on the basics but never showing advance skills.

Comment: Try Blender cloud, they have many tutorials in training section on rigging and animation, you have to subscribe for that.

Comment: BS&E  Blender Shock and Exacerbation.  Another case.  When you wrote .. [But I must be doing something wrong] ... I suggest you edit this to  .... I have an inefficient workflow and education in weight painting, how can I improve my weight painting skills ? And put this sentence as the very first sentence of the question.  The rest of the question is entertaining and is secondary.  Please know I had BS&E for the first 30 days of using Blender.  I still get flare ups.  I can not even write what I said about Blender.  There might be consequences.  Blender education is better now. Many Videos.

Comment: When I have searched for Blender (B) training on the internet, various sites show up.  You are probably a better web searcher than I.  Most of the time I see videos on the site that rhymes with Moo Moob.  Perhaps they just dominate search results.  For weight painting I suggest you see a rare high quality  video 3 times ... or more commonly, at least 5 different average quality videos.  That is the nature of Moo Moob.  Your public library may have electronics books on B.  I prefer video training for Blender because I see the video on the computer.  B training often takes mutliple sources.

Comment: I suggest reducing your question to the specific issue you are having and add images to illustrate that. I think being specific will help you get an answer to your question as opposed to "I don't think I'm very good at weight painting", which is what the majority of your question seems to be about.

Comment: The point I'm making: Why am I such a pro with other software but Blender. What is so difficult about Blender that makes me incompetent with just this particular software? Saying "I have an inefficient workflow and education in weight painting" would be completely inaccurate, I have the skill and the know how but not with Blender. So there must be some method I am not applying to use Blender for weight painting.

Comment: So there must be some method I am not applying to use Blender for weight painting. Maybe there are techniques and approaches that only apply to this software that eludes me.

Comment: Hello Eric, the sad truth is Blender tools are less powerful and advanced as in other commercial software. Everything can be done, but it requires more work and time. Discovering this will gain you a new respect for people making stunning artworks with Blender. Weight painting tools and sculpt tools are basic in Blender. However they are improved version to version - not quite there yet but closer and closer.

Comment: This is a major bug fix, missing a properly functioning smooth brush might as well not have any weight painting tools at all. I've been using it for a while now and it is very enjoyable to weight paint.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is Blender v2.78

Weight Paint bug fix for v2.78: Blur now smooths between connected weights

Previously it would average all the points under the brush and applying that value, giving an off a feedback loop that often depended on the direction of the brush stroke, giving a not-very-useful smearing effect. Now blend brush smooths between connected edges as it should.

Now there is a real smooth brush that was greatly needed. Now I can do all the weight painting in Blender, also I discovered Alt+B to make a square slice to isolate part of a shape to have an unobstructed view of where you need to edit.